# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What does this error mean?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Be6u.png)

this happens when I put my filteredData variable inside the `tr` tag of the table.

```
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Original email</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <template>
      <tr v-if="(fiteredData = '')">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr
        v-else
        v-for="data in filteredData"
        :key="data.ind_id"
        :value="data.ind_id"
      >
        <td>{{ data.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
        <td>
          <button @click="sendProps(data)">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
```

This is my method:

```
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedData: "",
      filteredData: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    searchResult(e) {
      this.filteredData = this.fetchedData.filter((data) => {
        return data.email.toLowerCase().includes(this.email.toLowerCase());
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.filteredData);
    }
```

fetchedData get the data from this:

```
  async mounted() {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/individuals").then((result) => {
      this.fetchedData = result.data;
      console.log(this.fetchedData);
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this: `<tr v-if="(filteredData = '')">` should be: `<tr v-if="filteredData === ''">`, or even beter: `v-if="!filteredData.length"`. You've misspelled the variable name and are accidentally setting it to an empty string rather than doing a comparison (we've all been there, I'm sure)

On a related note, I would initialize `fetchedData` and `filteredData` as empty arrays, not strings, because `v-for` is meant to iterate over objects and arrays, not strings (even though it's probably smart enough to handle it).

Comment: Thank you for your help Brother! I didn't notice that. It's working now. But what does (reading 'subTree') mean?

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem in the past it was that the browser itself had an issue and opening my application in a new private window worked.